# Python changes multiple list items even though I ask it to change only one

Tags: python, sqlite, replace

I have a weird problem that I can't figure out. When I ask `Python` to `.replace` `row[2]` it also changes the value of `row[1]`. It only happens at times when `row[1]` and `row[2]` are the same value *before* I change `row[2]`.

I'm `querying` my `database` like this:

```
c_lime.execute("SELECT * FROM lime_database_table WHERE {} = ? ORDER BY time_start ASC".format(table_column), [user_query])
for row in c_lime.fetchall():

    #ROW IS (2.31568438882786e+38, '1/8/2015 8:00:00 AM', '1/8/2015 9:00:00 AM')

    passed_row = row[1]

    #HERE I SUCCESSFULLY REPLACE row AT POSITION row[1]
    replaced_row = str(row).replace(row[1], convert_time_zone(passed_row))

    #NOW row[1] is '1/8/2015 9:00:00 AM', the same as row[2]

    passed_row2 = row[2]

    #HERE I REPLACE row[2]
    replaced_row2 = str(replaced_row).replace(row[2], convert_time_zone(passed_row2))

    print(replaced_row2)
```

Now I expect `row[1]` to be `'1/8/2015 9:00:00 AM'` as before and `row[2]` to be `'1/8/2015 10:00:00 AM'` but for some odd reason both are `'1/8/2015 10:00:00 AM'`. This bug *only* happens when `row[1]` is one hour less than `row[2]`. Otherwise it works flawlessly, adding 1 hour to `row[1]` and `row[2].`

If it helps, I'll post the code for the `convert_time_zone` method:

```
def convert_time_zone(passed_row):
change_date = passed_row
print(str(change_date))
tz = time_zone

my_time_list = list(change_date)
counter = 0
for i in my_time_list:
    if i == ":":
        print("Found :  Counter is " + str(counter))
        print("\nBEFORE: " + str(''.join(my_time_list)) + "\n")

        if my_time_list[counter - 1] == "9":
            my_time_list[counter - 1] = str(tz - 1)

            if my_time_list[counter - 2] == " ":
                my_time_list[counter - 2] = " 1"
            elif my_time_list[counter - 2] != " ":
                my_time_list[counter - 2] = " " + str(int(my_time_list[counter - 2]) + tz)

            print("AFTER: " + str(''.join(my_time_list)) + "\n")
        elif my_time_list[counter - 1] == "2" and my_time_list[counter - 2] == "1" and tz > 0:
            my_time_list[counter - 1] = str(tz)
            my_time_list[counter - 2] = " "
            print("AFTER: " + str(''.join(my_time_list)) + "\n")
        else:
            my_time_list[counter - 1] = str(int(my_time_list[counter - 1]) + tz)
            print("AFTER: " + str(''.join(my_time_list)) + "\n")

        my_time_list = str(''.join(my_time_list))
        print(my_time_list)

        break
    counter += 1
return my_time_list
```

Comment: Python only does what you ask it. If you don't know what you're asking it then that's on you. Put some print statements printing `i` and the values you're changing in your loop and see where the code is going wrong. This is called debugging or at least a form of it

Comment: *" It only happens ... when ... are the same value"*: This is **default** behavior **"all occurrences of substring old replaced by new"** Read about [str.replace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace), there is a **count** parameter ` str.replace(old, new[, count])`

Comment: Yeah, I finally figured it out. I read it as `row[2]` being replaced, when it was ALL STRINGS WITH THAT NAME that were replaced. Just changed the replace order and now it works fine, thanks :)